# Meteor: relative/absolute path issue

Tags: meteor

I'm testing out some old code and I'm getting an error and it looks like its with these lines of code:

```
var targetFile='../../../../../public/image1.png';
var sourceFile='../../../../../../game4-dirs/public/image2.png';

fs.writeFileSync(targetFile, fs.readFileSync(sourceFile));
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: ENOENT, unlink '../../../../../public/image1.png'
```

I seem to vaguely remember that `public` and `game4-dirs` aren't  accessible like this relatively to the product but relatively to where meteor is installed to (or something like that, I can't quite remember).

Has this change in version 1.2.0.2?  I was originally using v0.9.3.1

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Meteor application lives at `myApp` on disk then files under `myApp/public` will be available at root in HTML `/`. This means the url for `image1.png` should be simply `/image1.png`.

It looks like `../../../../../../game4-dirs/public/image2.png` is trying to access a file that is not *below* your meteor app's root directory. Meteor won't allow this on the client for obvious security reasons. If you want to use `image2.png` you should move it to your app's `/public` directory and then refer to it in html with simply `/image2.png`

Comment: Looks like that was certainly part of it, thank you.  My old code seemed to work ok though even though it was using directories at the same directory level as my app.... anyway that's one less problem :)